# C, How to use this tree struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have an assignment that involves reading Assembly code, figuring out what it does, and then writing it as C code. I'm having a hard time understanding how to use the given C code though, it is this:

```
typedef struct ELE *tree_ptr;

struct ELE {
    long val;
    tree_ptr left;
    tree_ptr right;
};
```

With this prototype (if that matters):

```
long traverse(tree_ptr tp);
```

Can someone show me how to properly create one, set its val field, and print it? This causes a segmentation fault:

```
int main () {
    tree_ptr tp;
    tp->val = 5;
    //printf("%lu\n", tp->val);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tree_ptr` is a pointer to `struct ELE`

So your code is similar to

```
struct ELE * tp;
tp->val = 5;
```

In the above code, you've created a pointer to `struct ELE`, but it doesn't actually point to any valid memory region.

To fix your code, try this

```
// allocation on heap
tree_ptr tp = malloc(sizeof(struct ELE));
tp->val = 5;
```

or you can try...

```
// allocation on stack
struct ELE tp;
tp.val = 5;
```

Comment: You need to allocate space and set that pointer or `tp->val` will do bad things.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I had to allocate space. New to C, pointers, and structs

Comment: @asimes you're welcome :-) here's a short tutorial on C pointers at http://www.openismus.com/documents/cplusplus/cpointers.shtml

Comment: Those three instructions are very handy, I still get them mixed up. What is special about this code that needed to use `malloc()`?

Comment: You don't have to use `malloc()`... it's just when you're declaring a variable of type `tree_tr` you're **actually** creating a pointer type to `struct ELE`. So, this variable needs to point to some address. (in this case, you don't have another `struct ELE` type variable floating around for your `tp` to point to, so I just gave you the malloc solution. but really you don't need to use malloc)

Answer (score 2):

`tree_ptr` is really just a `ELE *`. The important part is that `*`. It's a *pointer*. It needs memory. Pointers need to be associated with a valid memory address before you can use them. Some possible options are:

Option 1:

```
tree_ptr tp;
tp = malloc(sizeof(*tp)); // allocate memory for it, don't forget to free() it!
```

Option 2:

```
struct ELE tp; // Don't even use a pointer at all...
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I have to try to make sense of it as `tree_ptr tp` because it is in the prototype.